# C# + asp.Net + Custom Sybase SessionState provider + ReportViewer = some reports crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, reportviewer2008

I'm using a Custom Session State provider to store our session data in our Sybase Database.

It's working well, but some reports in the report viewer control consistantly cause the following crash.

System.Web.HttpException: The session state information is invalid and might be corrupted.
Generated: Thu, 02 Apr 2009 20:21:47 GMT

System.Web.HttpException: The session state information is invalid and might be corrupted.
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
   at JCDCHelper.Providers.JCDCSybaseSessionProvider.SybaseCustomSessionData.Deserialize(HttpContext context, String serializedItems, Int32 timeout)
   at JCDCHelper.Providers.JCDCSybaseSessionProvider.SybaseCustomSessionData.GetSessionStoreItem(Boolean lockRecord, HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at JCDCHelper.Providers.JCDCSybaseSessionProvider.SybaseCustomSessionData.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I've tried blocking null keyNames, and no joy.

I've tried Manually serializing the EntityObjects that contain the data for the report and they serialize and deserialize just fine.

I'm not running out of memory, the same reports crash and the same reports don't crash regardless of my memory load.

I've googled everything I can think of, but I'm flummoxed.

Everything thing else is working as expected, Serializing and Deserializing just fine.

Does anyone have any ideas or hints?

Thanks

Caladin-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We gave up on this one a re-wrote the reports in crystal Reports, and 
build the PDFs by hand. (not using CrystalReportsViewer) and it
worked.

Hope that helps someone.